# SQL - EXCEPTION TO A JOIN STATEMENT

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I have two tables I would like to join. One has currency references and the other has the names for the currency references. It is like a regular inner join exercise with one exception. The currency reference of 0 in the first table is actually 160 in the other. How can I manipulate my join statement to overcome this problem?

TABLE 1

> ```
>        CREDIT TYPE               TRCURR
>           CAR LOAN                    0
>      CONSUMER LOAN                    0
>           CAR LOAN                   20
>           CAR LOAN                    1
> ```

TABLE 2

> ```
>   CURRENCYREF     NAME_
>             1       EUR
>            20       YEN
>           160       USD
> ```

Note that all `TRCURR` - `CURRENCYREF` combinations are correct except for the fact that the currency `160` is `0` in TABLE 1.

THANKS!

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server? you have both tagged

Comment: It is SQL server, but I selected both as this is a basic SQL question. Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use multiple conditions in join statements like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.trCurr = t2.currencyRef
    or (t1.trCurr = 0 AND t2.currencyRef = 160)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use CASE, for example, firstly and then make an INNER JOIN statement
So, it like :

```
 select * from (
 select case when tabl.TRCURR = 0 then  '160',
             when tabl.TRCURR = 1 the   '...' end as TRCURR, tabl.* 
 from table_1 tabl) t1
 inner join table_2 t2
 on t1.TRCURR = t2.CURRENCYREF
```

something like that

Answer (score 1):

I don't know I understood your requirements properly or not but as per my understanding you can try below query for your exception case as it will overcome mismatching 0 = 160 barrier.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE1  t2 ON t1.TRCURR = t2.CURRENCYREF OR (t1.TRCURR = 0 AND t2.CURRENCYREF = 160)
```

Thank you